# Can I run two different scripts on a pm2 service?

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, server, pm2

Can I run one nodejs script and one python script at the same time, on one ubuntu server with the pm2 service?

Or do I have to use two same scripts?

I tried to find some information about it but I didn't found anything. I only know that it is possible to run nodejs scripts and python scripts and other scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run many process with pm2.

Just issue a `pm2 start` command for each process you want to run.

```
pm2 start -n "Process 1" /path/to/process1
pm2 start -n "Process 2" /path/to/process2
pm2 start -n "Process 3" /path/to/process3
...
```